# limiting files reading to some while using list.files

Tags: r

I have temperature data files in my parent directory in the following formats air_temp.1901, air_tem.1902 .......

And to read them I am using the following line on commands:

`

```
#list all files in the folder
p=list.files(pattern = "air_temp.*")

#make a function to extract data from Uni_Del files
read_udel = function(p){
  d = read.fwf(p, widths=rep(8,15))
  names(d) = c("long","lat",month.abb,"mean")
  return(d)
}

#Make a list of that contains all data
read.all = lapply(p, read_udel)`
```

But since I don't want data from all the years, i want to list.files to read only a part of files for example from 2010-2015. I tried for loop to do this but did't work.

could someone please tell me what I might do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the pattern to get only years we need, something like:

```
p <- list.files(pattern = "air_temp201[0-5]")
```

Alternatively, if we know we have files for all the years, we can use *paste*:

```
p <- paste0("air_temp", 2010:2015)
```

Comment: just one follow up, since my data is from 1900, the way you suggested would work if i have 3 digits common in upper and lower bound values. since I want from 1990 to 2015, it won't be applicable.  Could you suggest some way.

Comment: @crawling_ec do you have data for all the years starting 1990 to 2015?

Comment: @crawling_ec if you do, then we can just paste: `p <- paste0("air_temp", 1990:2015)`

Comment: ohhh wow! I did even think I could use paste0. Thank u so much!!!!!!